# Alguma forma dinâmica de selecionar IDs com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, front-end

Gostaria de saber uma possibilidade de um algoritmo para eu venha selecionar um um DOM de uma forma mais dinâmica, sem ter a necessidade de usar o `getElementById` toda a vez.

Eu gostaria de selecionar todos os elementos e manipular no JS. Alguém pode me ajudar nisso, por favor?

```
<section id="step00" class="slide">        
</section>

<section id="step01" class="slide">        
</section>
```

Na verdade, estou tentando exibir e esconder os passos a cada click. Tipo Step By Step.

Imagine eu ter que fazer tudo isso:

```
const step00 = document.getElementById('step00')
const step01 = document.getElementById('step01')
const step02 = document.getElementById('step02')
const step03 = document.getElementById('step03')
const step04 = document.getElementById('step04')
const step05 = document.getElementById('step05')
const step06 = document.getElementById('step06')
const step07 = document.getElementById('step07')
const step08 = document.getElementById('step08')
const step09 = document.getElementById('step09')
const step10 = document.getElementById('step10')
const endTutorial = document.getElementById('endTutorial')

function initTutorial() {
    showStep00()
}

function showStep00() {
    console.log('Inicio o passo 0')
    step00.removeAttribute('hidden')
    step01.setAttribute('hidden', 'true')
}

function showStep01() {
    console.log('Inicio o passo 1')
    step00.setAttribute('hidden', 'true')
    step01.removeAttribute('hidden')
}
```

Deve existir algo mais dinâmico, onde quando eu clicar em um botão com `onclick="step03"`, por exemplo, todos os outros botões são escondidos.

Comment: Selecione pela classe, com getElementsByClassName(), assim seleciona todos de uma vez. Lembrando que vai retornar um array de elementos, aí você tem que percorrer o array pra fazer as alterações.

Comment: Como vc quer pegar o elemento? por clique?

Comment: Eu vou usar onclick no HTML para exibir e esconder os Steps()

Comment: eu vou atualizar meu caso para vcs verem o que estou tentando fazer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar `document.querySelectorAll(".slide")` para criar uma lista de nós com todos os elementos com a classe `.slide`. Para selecionar um elemento da lista, você pega pelo índice do elemento na lista de nós. Por exemplo, para selecionar o primeiro você usa o índice `[0]`:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".slide")[0];
```

Você não irá mais precisar de `id`s, podendo até removê-los se só os estava usando para esse propósito.

No seu caso, uma função genérica que poderá ser aplicada a todos os elementos da lista:

```
function showStep(i) {
    console.log('Inicio o passo 0')
    slides[i].removeAttribute('hidden')
    slides[i+1].setAttribute('hidden', true)
}
```

Onde o parâmetro `i` é o índice do elemento na lista de nós. O `i+1` selecionará o próximo elemento.

Ficaria assim:

```
let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
function initTutorial() {
    showStep(0)
}

function showStep(i) {
    console.log('Inicio o passo '+(i+1))
    slides[i].removeAttribute('hidden')
    // verifico se o próximo elemento existe
    if(i+1 < slides.length) slides[i+1].setAttribute('hidden', true)
}
```

**Um exemplo para ilustrar:**

```js
let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
function initTutorial() {
    showStep(0)
}

function showStep(i) {
    console.log('Inicio o passo '+(i+1))
    slides[i].removeAttribute('hidden')
    // verifico se o próximo elemento existe
    if(i+1 < slides.length) slides[i+1].setAttribute('hidden', true)
}

initTutorial();
```

```html
<section hidden class="slide">  
   Passo 1     
</section>

<section class="slide">      
   Passo 2
</section>
<button onclick="showStep(1)">Passo 2</button>
```

Comment: TOP! Muito bom! Obrigado mesmo! Eu preciso aprender a pensar de uma forma mais dinâmica, do que a genérica! Levei quase 300 linhas de códigos para fazer somente isso!

Comment: Me diga mais uma coisa....
Como faço para que, assim que eu exibir o passo 2, o passo 1 se esconda... pois sempre quando chega no ultima passo esta gerando erro.

Comment: Eu to no celular agora, assim q eu chegar em casa eu vejo pra vc, inclusive a questao do erro.

Comment: Consegui aqui.. eu tive que validar... e adicionar o i-1. slides[i - 1].setAttribute('hidden', true) e tbm acrescentei na validação do if slides[i - 1]